# question on rendering of variables in TeX

Tags: bug, mathjax

Okay, this is nothing urgent. I just don't know where else to ask. It is rather a trivial matter, but here goes:

When using the variable $z$, seen most frequently in complex analysis questions: $z$ ALWAYS appears to me as *less* bold than the other variables, a mere silhouette compared to other letters and/or characters in a give expression. When it appears next to, say, $x, y$, the other characters stand out much more clearly than does $z$.

I also have a very pronounced astigmatism, which might explain how I perceive given letters, and it may be that $z$ happens to be shaped in a way that my astigmatism impacts my perception of the character.

> But I have no problem with seeing z, only $z$!

I can see "$z$", it's just more faint than other characters.

(I need to add a tag, so I am adding "bug", but the "bug" might be my eyes.)

I just wanted to check in to see if any one else perceives the same, so I know if it's ME or MathJax!

Comment: Do you have the same problem with z as with $z$? Does the problem persist if you zoom-in the page?

Comment: The diagonal stroke of the $z$ is a bit thin.  I can see how the eye might tend to lose it.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example equation here where you find the difference particularly noticeable. :-)

Comment: I agree the LaTeX, math mode $z$ appears a little thinner on-screen than other characters. For me, this is less of an issue on a printed page, but your mileage may vary.